# MQTT with relative schema/protocol and domain in Angular app

Tags: angular, websocket

For web front ends, including Angular, my assumption is that its bad practice to hard-code the base URL for API or web socket requests into the UI code. This would include values such as: the protocol or schema, the hostname or domain and the port.

A better practice is to use relative URIs with a reverse proxy or API gateway at the server side. This makes the front end relocatable and independent of a particular deployment. This way the front end can easily run from anywhere including with and without HTTPS (i.e., `http(s)://foo.com`, `http(s)://bar.com` or `http(s)://localhost:4200`) and we do not need to provide different builds or use development vs. production configurations, etc. that complicate the development and deployment workflow.

Finally, with the `proxy.conf.json` feature of angular.json, we already get good support for this workflow.

For REST API calls, the solution is rather simple, as we can use relative paths in our requests, such as `this.httpClient.get('api/foo');` and the request will automatically use the active schema (i.e. HTTP or HTTPS) as well as the current hostname and port.

However, what happens when a web socket is involved? web sockets are required to use absolute URLs, so when I use `this.mqttClient.connect(uri)`, then `uri` needs to include the schema, domain and possibly the port. I cannot establish a connection using a relative path such as `/mqtt`.

As this must be a common use case, I am wondering if there are any APIs that I can use simplify the generation of a absolute URL? My current solution is to use the `window.location.*` fields to map them to a websocket URL.

As far as I am currently aware, I need to inject a `window` object (preferably using a `WINDOW` provider) and then use `window.location.origin` and build an absolute URL for the MQTT client.

Something like:

```js
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window : Window) {
  const origin = window.location.origin;
  const wsOrigin = ws.replace('http', 'ws');
  const mqttUrl = new URL('/mqtt', wsOriginUrl).toString();

  // use mqttUrl, which is now absolute, and connect to broker
}
```

Is there any solution that does not rely on `WINDOW` or where an Angular build-in class helps to create this absolute URL given a relative path?